# spark.RDD take(n) returns array of element n, n times

Tags: json, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm using code from https://github.com/alexholmes/json-mapreduce to read a multi-line json file into an RDD.

```
var data = sc.newAPIHadoopFile( 
    filepath, 
    classOf[MultiLineJsonInputFormat], 
    classOf[LongWritable], 
    classOf[Text], 
    conf)
```

I printed out the first n elements to check if it was working correctly.

```
data.take(n).foreach { p => 
  val (line, json) = p
  println
  println(new JSONObject(json.toString).toString(4))
}
```

However when I try to look at the data, the arrays returned from `take` don't seem to be correct.

Instead of returning an array of the form

```
[ data[0], data[1], ... data[n] ]
```

it is in the form

```
[ data[n], data[n], ... data[n] ]
```

Is this an issue with the RDD I've created, or an issue with how I'm trying to print it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out why `take` it was returning an array with duplicate values.

As the API mentions:

> ```
> Note: Because Hadoop's RecordReader class re-uses the same Writable object 
> for each record, directly caching the returned RDD will create many 
> references to the same object. If you plan to directly cache Hadoop 
> writable objects, you should first copy them using a map function.
> ```

Therefore in my case it was reusing the same LongWritable and Text objects. For example if I did:

```
val foo = data.take(5)
foo.map( r => System.identityHashCode(r._1) )
```

The output was:

```
Array[Int] = Array(1805824193, 1805824193, 1805824193, 1805824193, 1805824193)
```

So in order to prevent it from doing this, I simply mapped the reused objects to their respective values:

```
val data = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
    filepath,
    classOf[MultiLineJsonInputFormat],
    classOf[LongWritable],
    classOf[Text],
    conf ).map(p => (p._1.get, p._2.toString))
```